# PHP if statement will allow me to add items to database but will not let echo or alert in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I would really appreciate some help with this:

I have a search bar. You type your interest into the search bar and it adds that interest to the database. If your interest exists in the database (as in someone else has the same interest) it uses an if statement to say so.

This is my PHP file:

```html
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);//TO REMOVE THE ANNOYING KEYWORD ERRORS
function connect() {
    return new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mysite', 'username', 'pw', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
}

//GET THE USERS IP
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])){
  $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
}
elseif(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){
  $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
}
else{
  $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}

$pdo = connect();

//OUTPUT THE SEARCHBAR SUGGESTIONS (OBTAIN SUGGESTIONS FROM DATABASE)
$testing = '%'.$_POST['keyword'].'%';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM interests WHERE interestName LIKE (:testing) ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0, 10";
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':testing', $testing, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$list = $query->fetchAll();
foreach ($list as $rs) {
 $interestName = str_replace($_POST['keyword'], '<b>'.$_POST['keyword'].'</b>', $rs['interestName']);
 $interestlist = '<li onclick="set_item(\''.str_replace("'", "\'", $rs['interestName']).'\')">'.$interestName.'</li>';
 if (strlen($_POST['keyword']) > 0){
  echo $interestlist; //THIS IS THE SUGGESTION BAR OUTPUT WITH THE SUGGESTIONS
 }
 }
//EVERYTHING ABOVE THIS WORKS.. THIS IS THE ISSUE HOWEVER:

if(isset($_POST['counter'])=="counter"){
 //INSERT THE INTEREST INTO THE DATABASE, WITH THE USER'S IP.
 $interestid=$_POST['interestinput'];
 $insertion = "INSERT INTO users (ipaddress, interest)
 VALUES ('$ip', '$interestid')"; 
 $pdo->query($insertion);
 //INSERTION WORKS. NOW I WANT TO CHECK IF INTEREST EXISTS. IF IT DOES EXIST, PRINT 'Users exist!':
 $item ="SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE interest LIKE '$interestid'"; 
 $result = $pdo->query($item)->fetchAll();
 $counted = count($result); //COUNT NUMBER OF RESULTS, THEN INSERT IT AS A TEST.
 $insertion = "INSERT INTO users (ipaddress, interest)
 VALUES ('$ip', '$counted')";
 if (count($result) > 1) {
  $pdo->query($insertion); //TEST IF IT WORKS -- THIS INSERTS THE TOTAL NUMBER OF SAME INTERESTS. IT WORKS!
  //BUT..
  echo ("Users exist!"); //THIS DOES NOTHING?           <---------   THE ISSUE
  echo "<script> alert('Test'); </script>"; //THIS ALSO DOES NOTHING (as a test)
 }
}
?>
```

Here is the site with the JS, CSS, etc. to help understand this better:

```js
//THIS FUNCTION IS CALLED WHEN THE USER HITS ENTER:
function enterPressed(e, field) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        var tb = document.getElementById("searchbox");
  if (field.value.length > 0) {
   document.getElementById('searching').style.display='block';
   document.getElementById('searchdisappear').style.display='none';
   $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: './php/phprefresh.php',
   data: {interestinput: field.value, counter: "counter"},
   });
  }
 }
}

//THIS FUNCTION GIVES INTEREST SUGGESTIONS (PULLED FROM THE DATABASE):
function autocomplet() {
 var workchecker = 0
 var min_length = 1;
 var keyword = $('#searchbox').val();
 if (keyword.length == min_length) {
  $.ajax({
   url: './php/phprefresh.php',
   type: 'POST',
   data: {keyword:keyword},
   success:function(data){
    $('#interest_list_id').show();
    $('#interest_list_id').html(data);
   }
  });
  
 } else {
  $('#interest_list_id').hide();
 }
}

//THIS FUNCTION SETS THE SUGGESTION INTO THE SEARCH BOX WHEN CLICKED
function set_item(item) {
 $('#searchbox').val(item);
 $('#interest_list_id').hide();
}
```

```css
/*Input*/
input.interestsearch {
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 30px;
    width: 540px;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 22px;
 display: block;
 padding: 2px 2px 2px 8px;
 outline: none;
}

.input_container {
 padding: auto;
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: -10px;
    width: 520px;
 display: block;
 outline: none;
 font-size: 20px;
}

.input_container ul {
 list-style: none;
 border-radius: 15px;
 padding: 5px;
 color: black;
}

.input_container ul li:hover {
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-radius: 15px;
 cursor: pointer;
 width: 500px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang = "en">

 <head>
  <title>Testsite</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/main.css">
  <script src ="./js/search.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body">


<!-- SEARCH BAR -->
 <div id="searchdisappear" style="display:block;">
 <center><h1> INTEREST SEARCH </h1></center>
   <input class="interestsearch" id="searchbox" maxlength="200" type="text" title="Search for an interest" onkeyup="autocomplet();" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="enterPressed(event, searchbox);" placeholder="Search for an interest.."/>
  <div class="input_container">
  <ul id="interest_list_id"></ul>
  </div>
 </div>
 
<!-- CONNECTING PEOPLE WITH SAME INTEREST-->
  <div id="searching" style="display:none;">
   <center> <p>Finding people..</p></center>
  </div>

</html>
```

I can't seem to get my head around why this just doesn't seem to work. If it can add something to the database it should be able to carry out the 'alert' also, no?

I appreciate anyone's help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just edited that - was an error with my original post. Apologies! Problem persists :P

Comment: Please, don't test vs. `=== TRUE` unless you *absolutely need to know* it's the literal true boolean value. It's almost completely pointless as these functions are intended to return logically true values by default.

Comment: Thanks all. I've included further details with the site's full PHP JS, HTML, CSS to hopefully help debug the issue I'm having. I appreciate anyone's help!

Comment: There is an awful lot wrong with your code, but the problem you ask about is due to comparing the boolean output of isset() with a string. You need to learn how to read your code, then how to instrument and debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works

```
if (count($result) > 1) {
    if($pdo->query($insertion) === TRUE){ //inserts 'works' into the database as a test.
        echo "<script> alert('Test'); </script>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So to recap:

```
echo "<script>alert('Test');</script>"; //This works
if (count($result) > 1) {
    $pdo->query($insertion) === TRUE; // This works - APPARENTLY
    echo "<script>alert('Test');</script>"; // This DOES NOT work
}
```

The only "strange" thing there is that === comparison which is needless. You can just as well write

```
$pdo->query($insertion);
```

but this shouldn't have any appreciable effect on the script being output.

Check the HTML source that gets output. Unless `$pdo->query` is *also* outputting something that interferes with Javascript, such as another `<script>` tag or a comment or an open quote of some kind, there's no way this can be happening.

When I have to do it this way, I usually use something like:

```
echo 'ALPHA';
if (count($result) > 1) {
    echo 'BRAVO';
    $pdo->query($insertion);
    echo 'CHARLIE';
}
echo 'DELTA';
```

and then check what appears in the source, if anything does.

## Update

I suspect that the `if` returns false, and the inside code is not executed. You thought it was executing because there are traces of the insertion in the database, but what if it was a *previous* insertion? In such cases, always insert something containing a timestamp.

## Update 2

You have a (different) error here:

```
if (isset($_POST['counter']) == 'counter')
```

It appears to work because in PHP 'counter', being a nonempty string, is an integer with value 1; and isset($_POST['counter']), being set, is equivalent to an integer with value 1.

But you would get:

```
if (isset($_POST['counter']) == 'counter') {
    // This is true
}
if (isset($_POST['counter']) == 'Noshabkeming') {
    // This is true, too.
}
```

Now, **try with this code**:

```
// Just check that 'counter' key exists.
if (array_key_exists('counter', $_POST)) {

    $result = $pdo->query($item)->fetchAll();

    $counted = count($result);

    echo "<script> alert('Count is {$counted}. Deal with it'); </script>";
}
echo "<script>alert('Did you see an alert?');</script>";
```

Also, to get rid of "keyword errors", write this:

```
"this is a string with a {$variable}..."
```

instead of

```
"this is a string with a $variable..."
```

This will also allow you to write

```
"this is a string with an {$array['key']}."
```

Comment: Yup, that's the problem I'm having. I tested it the way you suggested also, and it does output Alpha and Delta, but not Bravo or Charlie. It's an odd one.

Comment: Ah, then it's clearer. $result is empty. Are you sure the insertion query you see in the database **is not an older one?**

Comment: 100% sure. I tested the insertion in a different way to be sure. It inserts the total number of 'interests' and it is inserting the correct number. Something that may help, I am using JavaScript to set style.display='none' when you input something on the search bar and hit enter. It sets the search bar to 'none' and the 'Searching for interests' text to 'block'. Might this have something to do with it? I'm very new to PHP so if I'm not explaining this nicely let me know! I appreciate your help also.

Comment: The fact that it does not write out 'Bravo' or 'Charlie' means that *it is not executing that `if` code*. So, it cannot be executing the insertion query, which is between Bravo and Charlie checkpoints. To be even surer you can put `die('Here I die!');` instead of `echo('Bravo');`. Then see whether it dies, or - as I suspect - it doesn't.

Comment: To help you understand the issue further, I've included my entire site's PHP, HTML, CSS and JS in my original post which will hopefully shed light on why this is happening. It might have something to do with my JS or the way I am going about this may be wrong. It's driving me mad! Thanks so much again for your help!

Comment: I'm still of the opinion that you aren't debugging this properly. Have you looked into Xdebug and step-by-step execution? There are clients to do that. Also you might be interested in some logging library to keep track of what the program does at each call.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, to get more control over the communication with the database, would be to separate the php and the javascript, like this:

**PHP** search.php, contains communication to the database, send and receive information to and from the database, returns either `false` or `null` if no information is found.

**HTML** search.html, contains javascript that send information and receives information from search.php, if information received is false or null, issue a alert, clockwise on the send part, if no communication with the database is possible.

**search.php**

```
...code to communicate with the database...

if ($result) {
    if ($pdo->query($insertion)){
        return true;
    } else { return false; }
} else { return false; }
```

**search.html** assuming you use jquery, for example:

```
<script>
$("#search-form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var search = $('#search-field');

    $.post("search.php", {query: search})
    .done(function(data) {
        if (!data or data === '') {
            alert("No results.");
        }
        alert("Search response: " + data );
    })
    .fail(function(data) {
        alert("Error: " + data);
    });
});
</script>
```

This way, if the database is unavailable, your whole page doesn't break, you can just tell the user that their is a problem or that there are no results, plus you can issue alert from whatever reason you need.

Comment: I really appreciate your comment. Since I just started learning php this is quite a lot for me to try and understand. Regardless, once I build a better understanding I'm sure I'll be able to carry that alternative out correctly. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Anuga, I've included further details in my original post with the full site's HTML, JS, PHP and CSS which I hope will make it easier for you to understand the issue I'm having. Would appreciate if you could take a look! Thanks!